# Turbolinks 5 not changing url in browser for already visited pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, browser-cache, turbolinks

Using `turbolinks` in my application with rails 4. Basically facing an issue due to turbolinks that when I click on any `link_to` which already visited , the request goes to server and  content of whole page changes but url in browser remains same.

After this on any link I click content changes but browser url remains same. I check by removing turbolinks and then this issue not appears. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution it might help you

```
<%= link_to "Policy", policy_path, :"data-no-turbolink" => true %>
```